# Structured Data Schema Types for Trading Card Game Cards

Tags: schema, structured-data

So, I run a website which has a card database for the old Star Wars Trading Card Game by Wizards of the Coast. [swtcg.com](https://swtcg.com) There are multiple sets/expansions and each of those has multiple cards.

If you google other trading card games like Magic the Gathering or Pokemon TCG, you SOMETIMES will get rich, carousel-style results for individual cards, and if you click one of the cards, you get the rich, graph sidebar result. It seems like google is aware that these are **Cards** from **Sets** for a **Trading Card Game**.

I have tried to search for sites that are using structured data to identify these types, but have only found one or two, and they are just using Product markup.

Does anyone have any advice for what types I should use? I would really like to get to the point where you could search for a card and could get a rich result on the side with details about each card.

I've tried Product, but only some of them are cards that are actually sold. Others are digital only and free. I've considered Article and Creative Work, but am just really stumped as to what the best options would be for me. Is there such a thing as custom types that aren't insanely difficult to implement?

Answer (score 0):

The contents of your website present a database for playing cards. Let's look at your web page representing one card **[100 Battle Droids](https://swtcg.com/Cards/Details/3324/100-Battle-Droids)**. In my humble opinion, this content is explicit Creative Work and this type can probably help you. Due to the fact that the subject of this web page is a game, the use of the embedded type **Game** can help you. For this type, you can use the **about** or **mainEntity** properties as alternatives.

The map that is presented in the content of this web page is an image. You can probably be helped by using the following **[Google guidelines for structured data for the Article type](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#non-amp)**:

> For best results, provide multiple high-resolution images (minimum of
> 300,000 pixels when multiplying width and height) with the following
> aspect ratios: 16x9, 4x3, and 1x1. For example:

```html
  {
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "image": [
    "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
  ]
}
```

You can use the free online calculator for the following aspect ratios:
**[4X3](https://www.size43.com/4by3-aspect-ratio-calculator/)** and **[16x9](https://www.size43.com/16by9-aspect-ratio-calculator/)**. To compress your images, you can search for image compressors on the web. I usually use **[Compressnow](https://compressnow.com/)** with the maximum level of 65%.

Using the Google Guides to optimize your images **[Google Image best practices](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016)** and **[UX to responsive images](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images)**.

Your information below the card is the table. The use of a responsive table (row only) for this data may probably help. You can use the W3 guide **[Generating JSON from Tabular Data on the Web](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-csv2json-20151217/)** to structure this data.

You can use **[Google guide to Dataset](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/dataset)** and the standard of W3 **[Data Catalog Vocabulary (DCAT) - Version 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-dcat-2/)** to create a database of your cards.